# Why the inverse of the inverse of one matrix is not itself in python?

Tags: numpy

Why the inverse of the inverse of one matrix is not itself in python?
Why the inverse of the inverse of one matrix is not itself in python?
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVCS4.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lis42.png)

Comment: Hi! It's better to type your example code into the post itself, rather than posting links to images.

Comment: But Matlab does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Deleted the previous answer, since I made a mistake copying the matrix)

Your matrix is perfectly singular, so the inverse does not actually exist. Due to limits of numerical precision, `numpy.linalg.inv` gives you a matrix with very large values that is the inverse of another (similar) matrix.

I don't know what Matlab does in this situation, but it's possible that it gives the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, which would behave as you describe. Note however that this is not the same thing as the inverse, which does not exist. In numpy, you can get the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse as `np.linalg.pinv`.